# (Congruence) Why does the std:: before the first thread make it print second?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo(){
    std::cout << "Thread 1 \n";
}

void bar(){
    std::cout<< "Thread 2 \n";
}
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(foo);
    thread t2(bar);
    
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives me an output of `Thread 1` \n `Thread 2`. However, when I change `std::thread t1(foo);` to `thread t1(foo);`, my output is `Thread 2` \n `Thread 1`. Why is this?

The compiler I'm using for this is: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: I flipped a dime and got tail. Then I flipped a quarter and got head. Why is this? There is no reason, it just happened this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `std::` has absolutely no impact here. You simply do not have any control over in which order the threads will be run so you can get any order.

Comment: I see! Thank-you. My book didn't seem to mention anything regarding it and I was just curious.

Comment: The OS schedules when threads run.  So your `thread` functions will run in whatever order the OS deems necessary.